# Github pages not showing change on site

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

My GitHub repository shows all my changes up-to-date: https://github.com/solankivj94/portfolio

That means I have uploaded the css changes and images.

But the background image is *not* showing here:  https://solankivj94.github.io/portfolio/

Why?

Comment: Everything is fine in the link mentioned, then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/github-pages-not-linking-to-css/85262):

Using `/` makes the URL “root-relative”, which is https://solankivj94.github.io instead of the expected https://solankivj94.github.io/portfolio/.

So you need to use a relative path, like `../css`.

Comment: oh yes, thank a lot. i forget about that becuase it working fine in vscode. thanx for help.